# How to set cookies on a response in a ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, performance, service-worker

In a fetch handler triggered by a page navigation, I tried to do this:

```
return event.respondWith(new Response('Hello!', {
  headers: {
    "Set-Cookie": "TestCookie=foo; path=/; Max-Age=60;"
    "TestHeader": "foo"
  }
}));
```

Then I loaded any URL in the browser, and got the "Hello!" body.  In Chrome devtools, I see the `TestHeader` set in the network panel. But the cookie is not showing up in the network panel, nor in the Application > Cookies viewer.  `document.cookie` also fails to produce it.

The request is initiated by a page navigation, so there's no opportunity to set `credentials: "include"` on the fetch from the browser tab.

Is it possible to add a cookie to a response in the ServiceWorker?  If not, is it possible to write cookies in any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some relevant information in the Fetch specification.

As per https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name:

> A forbidden response-header name is a header name that is a
>   byte-case-insensitive match for one of:
>
> - `Set-Cookie`
> - `Set-Cookie2`

And then as per item 6 in https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-headers-append:

> Otherwise, if guard is "response" and name is a forbidden response-header name, return.

This restriction on adding in the `Set-Cookie` header applies to either constructing new `Response` objects with an initial set of headers, or adding in headers after the fact to an existing `Response` object.

There is a plan to add in support for reading and writing cookies inside of a service worker, but that will use a mechanism other than the `Set-Cookie` header in a `Response` object. There's more information about the plans in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/707).

Answer (score -1):

You may try following:

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
    let response = await fetch(request.url, request);       
    // Copy the response so that we can modify headers.
    response = new Response(response.body, response)
    response.headers.set("Set-Cookie", "test=1234");
    return response;
}
```